# The probability that 7 people taking an elevator will leave it in configuration 3-2-1-1

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm learning some probability and i'm doing some additional tasks, unfortunately without hints or answers.

Task:

We have 7 people in the elevator in 10 level building. They are leaving the elevator randomly. What's the probability of people leaving the elevator in configuration 3-2-1-1? 
It is: First 3 people leave the elevator, then 2, then 1 and finally 1.

My thinking: 
All possible configurations of people leaving the elevator is $10^7$, cause every person can leave on any floor.

How do i count those configurations? 
Let's pick four floors: $\binom{10}{4} = 630$, floors are numbered, so 3 people leave on first floor picked and so on...

It leaves me with probability equal to $$\frac{630}{10^7}=\frac{63}{10^6}$$
Is this solution correct? If yes, can we do it better/smarter?

I'd love some comments or ideas on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${}_{10}C_4$ is 210, not 630.

Then the only thing you have left to factor in is the number of ways people can be chosen for it. So you need to multiply by ${}_7C_3$ and ${}_4C_2$ and ${}_2C_1$ and ${}_1C_1$, or 420, giving a final answer of

$$\frac{210\cdot420}{10^7}.$$

Comment: I have no idea why i calculated C(10,4) as 630... Woops!

Answer (score 1):

I have a different answer. I assume that people exit in 4 different(distinct) groups of sizes 3, 2, 1 and 1 and they exit in different floors. I choose 4 floors out of 10 by $10C_{4} = 210$ ways. On the chosen 4 floors the 4 groups can be distributed in $(4C_{1})(3C_1)(2C_1)(1C_1) = 24$ ways. Hence, my answer is $\frac{210X24}{10^7}=\frac{5040}{10^7}$.

Comment: The groups are not pre-made; we have to factor in the ways the different people can be chosen to be in the group, since our sample space took their individuality into account.